# Prove or disprove that the given expression is "always" positive

Tags: probability, integration, probability-distributions, hilbert-spaces, convex-optimization

I have previously asked a question and I tried to solve it by my own and it led to the question below:

> Prove or disprove that
>
> $$\small\int_{\mathbb{R}}l(y)^xf_0(y)\mathrm{d}y\int_{\mathbb{R}}f_0(y)l(y)^x\ln (l(y)^x)\ln (l(y))\mathrm{d}y-\int_{\mathbb{R}}l(y)^xf_0(y)\ln (l(y))\mathrm{d}y\int_{\mathbb{R}}f_0(y)l(y)^x\ln (l(y)^x)\mathrm{d}y$$
>
> is greater than $0$.

Given:

$\rightarrow f_0$ and $f_1$ are some density functions

$\rightarrow l(y)=\frac{f_1(y)}{f_0(y)}$ is an increasing function.

$\rightarrow x\in(0,1)$

Comment: You can drop the denominator...

Comment: @julien thanks, done!

Comment: The first thing to do would be to consider the convergence of $\int \ell(y)^xf_0(y)dy$.

Comment: @julien yes it must be convergent as $\int f_1(y)^xf_0(y)^{1-x}$ is just some weighted multiplication of densities.

Comment: Yes, that's by Holder. And that's a start.

Comment: Okay assume I showed that is is convergent. How it will help me in the next step?

Comment: Weighted $L^2$. See below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an application of [Cauchy-Schwarz](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Schwarz_inequality) in disguise. It suffices to find the appropriate Hilbert space. And then show that the relevant functions actually belong to it. The latter is the tedious part of this exercise.

Consider the positive function $w(y)=\ell(y)^xf_0(y)=f_1(y)^xf_0(y)^{1-x}$. By Holder, it is integrable over $\mathbb{R}$. Now consider the [weighted $L^2$ space](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lp_space#Weighted_Lp_spaces) $L^2_w(\mathbb{R})$ equipped with the inner product

> $$
> (g,h)_w:=\frac{\int_\mathbb{R}g(y)h(y)w(y)dy}{\int_\mathbb{R}w(y)dy}
> $$

and the resulting norm $\|g\|_w=\sqrt{(g,g)_w}$. Note that $g$ is in $L^2_w$ if, by definition, $g^2w$ is integrable over $\mathbb{R}$.

Observing $\ln(\ell(y)^x=x\ln(\ell(y))$, what you want to show boils down to 
$$
\left(\int_\mathbb{R} \ln(\ell(y))w(y)dy\right)^2< \left(\int_\mathbb{R} (\ln(\ell(y)))^2w(y)dy\right) \left(\int_\mathbb{R} (w(y)dy\right).
$$
Dividing by $\left(\int_\mathbb{R} (w(y)dy\right)^2$, this reads

> $$
> (g,1)_w^2< \|g\|_w^2=\|g\|_w^2\|1\|_w^2\qquad\mbox{with}\;\;g(y)=\ln(\ell(y)).
> $$

This follows from Cauchy-Schwarz. Note that this will be a strict inequality as $g$ and $1$ are linearly independent, since $\ell$ is increasing.

It only remains to prove that $g$ belongs to $L^2_w$, i.e. $\int_\mathbb{R} g(y)^2w(y)dy<\infty$. This is where the assumption $\ell$ increasing comes into play.

If $g$ is bounded, the claim is obvious. If not, since $\ell$ is increasing and positive, this means that either $\lim_{+\infty} \ell=+\infty$ or $\lim_{-\infty} \ell=0$. So assume, to begin with, that $\lim_{+\infty} \ell=+\infty$. Now write
$$
(\ln \ell(y))^2w(y)=(\ln \ell(y))^2\ell(y)^xf_0(y)   =\frac{(\ln \ell(y))^2}{\ell(y)^\frac{1-x}{2}}\ell(y)^\frac{1+x}{2}f_0(y)=\frac{(\ln \ell(y))^2}{\ell(y)^\frac{1-x}{2}}f_1(y)^\frac{1+x}{2}f_0(y)^\frac{1-x}{2}.
$$
By Holder, the function $f_1(y)^\frac{1+x}{2}f_0(y)^\frac{1-x}{2}$ is integrable. Now
$$
\lim_{+\infty} \frac{(\ln \ell(y))^2}{\ell(y)^\frac{1-x}{2}}=0.
$$
So $g(y)^2w(y)$ is integrable over $[0,+\infty)$ by comparison with $f_1(y)^\frac{1+x}{2}f_0(y)^\frac{1-x}{2}$. If $\lim_{-\infty}\ell>0$, then $g$ is bounded on $(-\infty,0]$ and integrability over $(-\infty,0]$ follows. If $\lim_{-\infty}\ell=0$, then write
$$
(\ln \ell(y))^2w(y)=(\ln \ell(y))^2\ell(y)^xf_0(y).
$$
Now
$$
\lim_{-\infty}(\ln \ell(y))^2\ell(y)^x=0
$$
hence integrability over $(-\infty,0]$ follows by comparison with $f_0$. n any case, we have proven that $g$ belongs to $L^2_w$, which completes the argument.

Comment: Ok just checking, one min.

Comment: what is $h$ in $(g,h)_w$, perhaps $f$?

Comment: @SeyhmusGüngören ? No I just define $(g,h)_w$ for arbitrary functions such that $g^2w$ and $h^2w$ are integrable. This defines the inner product structure on $L^2_w$, the set of all $g$ such that $g^2w$ is integrable. I chose the letters $g,h$ randomly. Use $f$ if you prefer.

Comment: I see. I am not familiar with $L_w^2$, I am currently reading your wiki post. I only checked the right and left side of the equation, i saw the term $h$ on the left side but not on the right side, thats the reason I asked, perhaps it was $f$.

Comment: @SeyhmusGüngören Right, thanks and sorry, this is a typo. Fixed.

Comment: @SeyhmusGüngören I fixed one more thing: strict inequality, not large. That was not difficult, but it had t o be mentioned.

Comment: I have read your post once again and checked wikipedia as well. I guess I still have alot to learn, and I have some questions about the solution. I will write them as an answer.

Comment: $3$ is also clear. At part $2$, $g(0)$ should be finite. Is it possible that $g(0)$ is infinite? I go to bed now) good night.

Comment: THe way I understand $\ell$ is increasing is that it only takes finite positive values and is increasing. Otherwise, it would be infinite on some $[x_0,+\infty)$ and the problem wouldn't be very interesting, as everything would be infinite.

Comment: Yes, your understanding is completely correct. I was only trying to evaluate all possibilities to be complete but it is not a possibility as you said. Thank you very much again for your help and kind responses.