# Is this question solvable? $2$ non-linear equations and the proof that the solution is unique

Tags: probability, integration, probability-distributions, hilbert-spaces

As mentioned in the title I want to show the uniqueness of the solution to $2$ non-linear equations. However, it seems that I can not solve this question with my current mathematical knowledge. More than this I am not aware about the difficulty of the problem. Is this question solvable by a very good mathematician at all? This is also what I wonder very much.

Let me introduce my problem:

I have orgininally $4$ equations as given below.

$$\int_{-\infty}^{y_l}\frac{b}{eb^{\mu_1}}f_1(y)\mathrm{d}y+\int_{y_l}^{y_u}K_1 l(y)^{\frac{-\ln(b)}{\ln(a b)}}f_1(y)\mathrm{d}y+\int_{y_u}^{\infty}\frac{1}{eb^{\mu_1}}f_1(y)\mathrm{d}y=1$$

$$\int_{-\infty}^{y_l}\frac{1}{ea^{\mu_0}}f_0(y)\mathrm{d}y+\int_{y_l}^{y_u}K_0 l(y)^{\frac{\ln(a)}{\ln(a b)}}f_0(y)\mathrm{d}y+\int_{y_u}^{\infty}\frac{a}{ea^{\mu_0}}f_0(y)\mathrm{d}y=1$$

$$\small \int_{-\infty}^{y_l}\frac{b}{eb^{\mu_1}}\ln \left(\frac{b}{e b^{\mu_1}}\right)f_1(y)\mathrm{d}y+\int_{y_l}^{y_u}K_1 l(y)^{\frac{-\ln(b)}{\ln(a b)}}f_1(y) \ln \left( K_1 l(y)^{\frac{-\ln(b)}{\ln(a b)}}\right)\mathrm{d}y+\int_{y_u}^{\infty}\frac{1}{eb^{\mu_1}}\ln \left(\frac{1}{eb^{\mu_1}}\right)f_1(y)\mathrm{d}y=\epsilon_1$$

$$\small \int_{-\infty}^{y_l}\frac{1}{ea^{\mu_0}}\ln \left(\frac{1}{e a^{\mu_0}}\right)f_0(y)\mathrm{d}y+\int_{y_l}^{y_u}K_0 l(y)^{\frac{\ln(a)}{\ln(a b)}}f_0(y) \ln \left( K_0 l(y)^{\frac{\ln(a)}{\ln(a b)}}\right)\mathrm{d}y+\int_{y_u}^{\infty}\frac{a}{e a^{\mu_0}}\ln \left(\frac{a}{ea^{\mu_0}}\right)f_0(y)\mathrm{d}y=\epsilon_0$$

Given:

$\rightarrow f_0$ and $f_1$ are some density functions

$\rightarrow l(y)=\frac{f_1(y)}{f_0(y)}$ is an increasing function

$\rightarrow  b=l(y_u),\quad a=\frac{1}{l(y_l)}$

$\rightarrow K_0=\frac{e^{\frac{\ln^2(a)}{\ln (ab)}}}{e a^{\mu_0}},\quad K_1=\frac{e^{\frac{\ln^2(b)}{\ln (ab)}}}{e b^{\mu_1}}$

---

As you can see the first two equations can be inserted into the third and fourth equation via $e a^{\mu_0}$ and $e b^{\mu_1}$. As a result we can obtain

$$z_0=\int_{-\infty }^{y_l} f_0(y) \, \mathrm{d}y+\int _{y_l}^{y_u}e^{\frac{\text{ln}^2(a)}{\text{ln}(ab)}}l(y)^{\frac{\text{ln}[a]}{\text{ln}(ab)}}f_0(y)\mathrm{d}y+\int _{y_u}^{\infty }a f_0 (y)\mathrm{d}y$$

$$z_1=\int _{-\infty }^{y_l}b f_1(y)\mathrm{d}y+\int _{y_l}^{y_u}e^{\frac{\text{ln}^2(b)}{\text{ln}(ab)}}l(y)^{\frac{-\text{ln}[b]}{\ln (ab)}}f_1(y)\mathrm{d}y+\int_{y_u}^{\infty } f_1(y) \, \mathrm{d}y$$

$$h_0=-\text{ln}(z_0)+\frac{1}{z_0}\left(\int _{y_l}^{y_u}e^{\frac{\text{ln}^2(a)}{\text{ln}(ab)}}l(y)^{\frac{\text{ln}(a)}{\text{ln}(ab)}}\text{ln}\left(e^{\frac{\text{ln}^2(a)}{\text{ln}(ab)}}l(y)^{\frac{\text{ln}(a)}{\text{ln}(ab)}}\right)f_0(y)\mathrm{d}y+\int _{y_u}^{\infty }a\text{ln}(a)f_0 (y)\mathrm{d}y\right)=\epsilon_0$$

$$h_1=-\text{ln}(z_1)+\frac{1}{z_1}\left(\int _{y_l}^{y_u}e^{\frac{\text{ln}^2(b)}{\text{ln}(ab)}}l(y)^{-\frac{\text{ln}(b)}{\text{ln}(ab)}}\text{ln}\left(e^{\frac{\text{ln}^2(b)}{\text{ln}(ab)}}l(y)^{-\frac{\text{ln}(b)}{\text{ln}(ab)}}\right)f_1(y)\mathrm{d}y+\int _{-\infty}^{y_l }b\text{ln}(b)f_1 (y)\mathrm{d}y\right)=\epsilon_1$$

Now I have two functions $h_0(y_l,y_u)=\epsilon_0$ and $h_1(y_l,y_u)=\epsilon_1$.

**My conjecture:**

There exists a unique solution to $\{h_0(y_l,y_u)=\epsilon_0,\,h_1(y_l,y_u)=\epsilon_1\}$ with some $\{y_l,y_u\}\in\mathbb{R}$ for $\{\epsilon_0\in[0,h_0(y_l\rightarrow -\infty,y_u \rightarrow \infty)],\epsilon_1\in[0,h_1(y_l\rightarrow -\infty,y_u \rightarrow \infty)]\}$

**My Question:**

```
Prove or disprove if my conjecture is correct.
```

**Extra Information:**

When $y_l\rightarrow -\infty$ and $y_u\rightarrow \infty$, the first $4$ equations above simplifies considerably. Then, for the equation $h_0$ we have a single parameter $0<x=\frac{\ln(a)}{\ln(a b)}<1$. If we take the derivative with respect to $x$, we can show that it is positive. The latter part of this proof (to show that it is positive) can be seen here [Prove or disprove that the given expression is "always" positive](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/334781/prove-or-disprove-that-the-given-expression-is-always-positive) , thanks to @julien. I havent done by my own but I would guess that the similar story also applies to $h_1$, and this determines the set $\{\epsilon_0\in[0,h_0(y_l\rightarrow -\infty,y_u \rightarrow \infty)],\epsilon_1\in[0,h_1(y_l\rightarrow -\infty,y_u \rightarrow \infty)]\}$ for which a unique solution is sought for.

Comment: Please don't put information about a bounty in the title; it already automatically gets displayed alongside the title. (Also the question currently has a bounty of $50$ points, not $500$ points.)

Comment: @joriki I want to make something out of standard. So I want to offer asymmetric bounty. I hope it is not a problem. I want to give $500$ for the proof and $50$ for disproof and I know how I can give it.

Comment: This sounds like giving 500 points for a proof of the Riemann hypothesis and 50 points for its refutation $\ldots$

Comment: @ChristianBlatter funny). The proof should be much more difficult than finding an extreme and probably simple example which can disprove it. It also reflects that a proof makes me happier than this proof i mean disproof )).